# Compare two dates. Sqlite

Tags: android, database, sqlite, date, datetime

I have a sqlite database which has table of tasks which has a column of dueDates. I want to filter out the dates greater than tomorrow's date. So if tomorrow's date is 29 th april I should get the dates later than tomorrow.

For this I have converted string into date. The format is :

```
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    dateToday  = calendar.getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy");
     dueDateToday = df.format(dateToday);

    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
     dueTomorrow = calendar.getTime();

     dueDateTomorrow = df.format(dueTomorrow);
```

and the query is:

```
 public ArrayList<Task> getDueDatesLater(String tomorrow) {
    ArrayList<Task> conList = new ArrayList<Task>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TASK_TABLE + " WHERE " + KEY_DUE_DATE + " > '" + tomorrow + "'" ;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            Task task = new Task();

            task.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            task.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
            task.setTaskPriority(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));
            task.setAlertDate(cursor.getString(3));
            task.setAlertTime(cursor.getString(4));
            task.setDueDate(cursor.getString(5));

            task.setDueTime(cursor.getString(6));
            task.setList(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(7)));
            task.setStatus(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(8)));

            task.setAlertId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(9)));

            conList.add(task);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return conList;
}
```

but I am getting list as 0. There is no dates. Maybe my query is wrong. Please help.

EDIT: As suggested.

```
public ArrayList<Task> getDueDatesLater(String tomorrow) {
    ArrayList<Task> conList = new ArrayList<Task>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TASK_TABLE ;

    Date dueDate,tomorrowDate;
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    try {
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            Task task = new Task();

            task.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            task.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
            task.setTaskPriority(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));
            task.setAlertDate(cursor.getString(3));
            task.setAlertTime(cursor.getString(4));
            task.setDueDate(cursor.getString(5));

            task.setDueTime(cursor.getString(6));
            task.setList(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(7)));
            task.setStatus(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(8)));

            task.setAlertId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(9)));


            dueDate = simpleDateFormat1.parse(task.getDueDate());
            tomorrowDate = simpleDateFormat1.parse(tomorrow);
            if (dueDate.getTime() > tomorrowDate.getTime()) {
                conList.add(task);
            }


            Log.d("laterQuery", selectQuery);

            //conList.add(task);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    }

    catch (ParseException e) {

    }

    return conList;
}
```

Still the list returns 0.

Same I want to get the count of how much tasks has dates later than tomorrow.

```
 public int getPendingTasksLaterDays(String tomorrow) {
    ArrayList<Task> conList = new ArrayList<Task>();


    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TASK_TABLE + " WHERE " + KEY_TASK_STATUS + " = 0";
    Date dueDate,tomorrowDate;
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor mCount= db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);

    if (mCount.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            count = mCount.getInt(0);
        } while (mCount.moveToNext());
    }

    Log.d("query",selectQuery);

    Log.d("count",String.valueOf(count));
    mCount.close();

    return count;
}
```

How to add in this?

Comment: which type of date format you saved in DB table ?

Comment: format is d MMM yyyy. @Rohitashv jain

Comment: so your date comparison failed when you compare or apply sqlite  query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you can put filter in query result.. it will work.

```
public ArrayList<Task> getDueDatesLater(String tomorrow) {
ArrayList<Task> conList = new ArrayList<Task>();

String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TASK_TABLE ;

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

 try {
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {

        Task task = new Task();

        task.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        task.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
        task.setTaskPriority(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));
        task.setAlertDate(cursor.getString(3));
        task.setAlertTime(cursor.getString(4));
        task.setDueDate(cursor.getString(5));

        task.setDueTime(cursor.getString(6));
        task.setList(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(7)));
        task.setStatus(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(8)));

        task.setAlertId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(9)));


        dueDate = simpleDateFormat1.parse(task.getDueDate());
        tomorrowDate = simpleDateFormat1.parse(tomorrow);
        if (dueDate.getTime() > tomorrowDate.getTime()) {
            conList.add(task);
        }
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
  }
}

catch (ParseException e) {

}

return conList;
```

}

Comment: tried this way. still the list returns 0 . please check edited qustion. @Nikhil Borad

Comment: it directly jumps to return conList after dueDate = simpleDateFormat1.parse(task.getDueDate());  and the list returns null. @Nikhil Borad

Comment: then simply its parseException.. it means that your date object  can't be convert into string. handle it with ParseException and you can find whats wrong going in..

Comment: I added format in simppleDateFormat and got the result.. Please check the edited question. THank you..@Nikhil Borad.

Comment: I have up voted dose not have that much reputations yet.. Please can you answer for another question ? @Nikhil Borad

Comment: I want to get the count of all tasks which is later than today. I can't check with    dueDate = simpleDateFormat1.parse(task.getDueDate());  as i dont have the task object here. please check the code in question. @Nikhil Borad

Comment: Simply make another function like this and put condition like greater than today and manage return... with return you can find count and even object also...

Comment: sorry not today I mean tomorrow.. as in the first method. @ Nikhil Borad

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String to_date = sdf.format(new Date());

crs = db.rawQuery(
      "SELECT _id, date_from, date_to, done_or_not, list_name " +
      "FROM list_tbl " +
      "WHERE " +
      "date_from <= Datetime('"+to_date+"') AND date_to >= Datetime('"+to_date+"')", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to compare any two dates from database or apply query on db your date format can be in any of the following formats:

```
YYYY-MM-DD
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS
HH:MM
HH:MM:SS
HH:MM:SS.SSS
```

// Your Query

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TASK_TABLE + " WHERE " + KEY_DUE_DATE + " > '" +2016-04-30 + "'" ;
```

or for the example

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE date BETWEEN "2011-01-11" AND "2011-8-11"
```

// below method change your date format ,if you want to show your date into different format on UI

```
//
/**
 * Change date for mate to original to target date format
 * return formatted date string
 * @param myDate
 * @return String
 */
public static String changeDateFormatIntoYYYYMMDDHHMMSS(String myDate,
                                                        String originalDateFormat,
                                                        String targetDateFormat){
    String formattedDate="";
    try {
        DateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(originalDateFormat);//AppConstant.DATE_FORMAT_FOR_UI);
        DateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(targetDateFormat);//AppConstant.DATE_FORMAT_FOR_DB);
        Date date = originalFormat.parse(myDate);
        formattedDate = targetFormat.format(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return formattedDate;
}

// calling Example 
String changeDate= changeDateFormatIntoYYYYMMDDHHMMSS("2016/04/30", DATE_FORMAT_FOR_DB,DATE_FORMAT_FOR_UI);

// String Formate
String DATE_FORMAT_FOR_DB="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss";
String DATE_FORMAT_FOR_UI="MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a";
```

This Code help's you in achieve your functionality

Comment: I tried to apply this method. But date string is not getting parse. @Rohitashv jain

Comment: date string not parse means what you are not able to fetch date from your db or any thing else?